# How to convert a gravitational force to speed and direction

Tags: orbit, gravity, solar-system

I am doing some calculations, and I wanted to know that after using the gravity equation, $$F = G \frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$$ if you can use $F$ and convert it into a speed, such as km/year, and also a direction or angle from the original direction. I am just looking into astronomy, and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must apply Newton's law
$$ m\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{v}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \boldsymbol{F}$$
which related the force $\boldsymbol{F}$ to the acceleration (=change of velocity). Note that positions, velocities, and forces are all **vector** quantities. Also note that as the objects move (change position), their mutual forces change (both direction and strength).

There is an enormous amound of literature on the resulting **orbits** for celestial bodies, going all the way back to Kepler and Newton. I suggest you look into elementary books or start with some Wikipedia articles.